# move between panels with the keyboard in atom

Tags: atom-editor

In atom, I often have multiple panels for different files, and I also have some panels for in-editor terminal. Is it possible to navigate between panels (change the focus) using only the keyboard?

Comment: check https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/panes/

Comment: It doesn't work when I'm in the terminal panel (I use the terminal-tab package). If the focus is in the terminal, the shortcut to switch panel doesn't work.

Comment: go to `Keybindings` and check `window:focus`

Answer (score 0):

go to `Keybindings` and check `window:focus` for changing panes window focus

1. `cmd-k-down`  window:focus-pane-**below**
2. `cmd-k-right` window:focus-pane-on-**right**
3. `cmd-k-left` window:focus-pane-on-**left**
4. `cmd-k-n`        window:focus-**next**-pane

Ref : https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/panes/